# Why is my copyTo function Not copying the mask to the correct Mat?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, android

I started with the following image, named `rgbaMat4Mask.bmp`:

[image]

Then I converted it to HSV, and then did `inRange()` to find contours, and got the following `Mat` named `maskedMat`:

[image]

Then I went on to draw the first contour (the bigger one), on a newly created empty `Mat` named `newMatWithMask`, which has been given *the **same size as that of the first image** I started with*:

[image]

**So far so good, but the problem starts now.** I created a new `Mat` and gave it the **same size as that of the first contour (the bigger one)**, and then set its background color to `new Scalar(120, 255, 255)`. Then I copied the `newMat4MaskFinished` to it using `copyTo` function. **But neither is the size of the resulting `Mat` same as that of the contour, nor is its background color set to `new Scalar(120, 255, 255)` which is blue.**

[image]

It is rather an image with size same as that of the entire mask, and has a black background. why? **What am I doing wrong?**

```
public void doProcessing(View view) {
        // READING THE RGBA MAT
        Mat rgbaMat4Mask = Highgui.imread("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/rgbaMat4Mask.bmp");

        // CONVERTING TO HSV
        Mat hsvMat4Mask = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbaMat4Mask, hsvMat4Mask, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/hsvMat4Mask.bmp", hsvMat4Mask);//check

        // CREATING A FILTER/MASK FOR RED COLORED BLOB
        Mat maskedMat = new Mat();
        Core.inRange(hsvMat4Mask, new Scalar(0, 100, 100), new Scalar(10, 255, 255), maskedMat);
        Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/maskedMat.bmp", maskedMat);// check

        // COPYING THE MASK TO AN EMPTY MAT
        // STEP 1:
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Imgproc.findContours(maskedMat, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

        //STEP 2: 
        Mat newMat4Mask = new Mat(rgbaMat4Mask.rows(), rgbaMat4Mask.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        newMat4Mask.setTo(new Scalar(0));
        Imgproc.drawContours(newMat4Mask, contours, 0, new Scalar(255), -1);//TODO Using -1 instead of CV_FILLED.
        Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/newMatWithMask.bmp", newMat4Mask);// check


        //STEP 3
        Log.i(TAG, "HAPPY rows:"+contours.get(0).rows()+"   columns:"+contours.get(0).cols());
        Mat newMatwithMaskFinished = new Mat(contours.get(0).rows(), contours.get(0).cols(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        newMatwithMaskFinished.setTo(new Scalar(120, 255, 255));
        rgbaMat4Mask.copyTo(newMatwithMaskFinished, newMat4Mask);
        Highgui.imwrite("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/newMatwithMaskFinished.bmp", newMatwithMaskFinished);//check*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `newMatwithMaskFinished` should have the same size as `rgbaMat4Mask` and `newMat4Mask`.

```
Mat newMatwithMaskFinished = new Mat(rgbaMat4Mask.rows(), rgbaMat4Mask.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
```

---

If you want to have a `Mat` of the bigger circle only, with *transparent* background, then you need to:

1) create `newMatwithMaskFinished` with type `CV_8UC4`

```
Mat newMatwithMaskFinished = new Mat(rgbaMat4Mask.rows(), rgbaMat4Mask.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
```

2) set a transparent background:

```
newMatwithMaskFinished.setTo(new Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

3) Compute the bounding box `box` of the contour you're interested in, with `boundingRect`.

4) Convert `rgbaMat4Mask` to 4 channels (unless it's already), with `cvtColor(..., COLOR_BGR2BGRA)`, let's call this `rgba`

5) Copy `rgba` to `newMatwithMaskFinished`, with mask `newMat4Mask`.

6) Crop `newMatwithMaskFinished` on `box`, using `submat` method

Comment: Oh. My aim behind all of this was to have a Mat of the bigger red circle only. The final effect I am after is to crop the `rgbaMat` such that only the bigger red blob remains, and everything else (i.e. the background as well as smaller red blob) discarded. Is that Not possible?

Comment: "If you want to have a Mat of the bigger circle only, with custom background.." - I need the bigger circle with _no_ background. I need the bigger circle only

Comment: So, transparent background?

Comment: Yes, a transparent background would do

Comment: About your update, say I do `Rect contourROI = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(0));  Mat detectedBlobRectangle = newMatwithMaskFinished.submat(contourROI);`, I will get a rectangle. It's background will still be black.